# Errors in Configuring FileZilla FTP Server

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I am looking for help in configuring FileZilla FTP Server.

The architecture of my ISP is like

> The router of the user with IP address such as 192.168.1.4, which is solely for LAN connections within a home network
>
> > Then comes the ISP LAN with lots of STATIC IP addresses such as 172.172.1xx.xx assigned to each user of the ISP
> >
> > > The third layer is the ISP itself with an external address such as 45.115.x.xxx. This very same address is used by many other individuals who are associated with the ISP.

So coming to the main point, I configured FileZilla server with the all the desired ports including 21, 990...etc being forwarded in the Windows Firewall as well as the Router. Got the NAT configured. Took care of the TLS settings and everything is running decent along with the Users & Groups configuration.

But I cannot get this server to work for file transfers from the internet, but works like a charm when I use my own devices to connect to the server at home (like a LAN).

So I am requesting for advice of what can be done to make the FileZilla work for External connections.

Note: In the PASV mode settings, I used the external IP address 45.115.x.xxx.
So I did not get this server to work since many users had the same external IP.

All I request you is what values must be placed in that PASV mode settings ?

Comment: May I ask what your purpose is? FTP is not the easiest to setup and if you just want to access your files I recommend SFTP instead as it uses only one port instead of several.

Comment: I require it for my website, mostly used just for testing purposes. Also I use it for data transfers between various devices in my LAN connection as well as sharing the data with my friends in various countries.

Comment: I would use SFTP for all except a few particular cases. Only caveat is users would need to be system users, while with FTP they are defined in an independent server application database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 45.115.x.xxx is a shared ip address, you would need your ISP to forward incoming connections to ports 21, etc to your home router ip 172.172.1xx.xxx. I doubt they would do that, however, since it means taking this possibility away from other users. My bet is they either offer a range of non standard ports that can be configured to redirect to your router, or the option of assigning you a dedicated external ip address where you can setup port forwarding at will.

Once you implement port forwarding for port 21 (you can `telnet 45.115.x.xxx 21` to check that it works), you need to define a range of ports in the FileZilla Server options and forward all those ports too.

From the FileZilla Server [documentation](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration) (slightly edited):

> If you have a NAT router, you need to tell FileZilla Server to use a
>   specific range of ports for passive mode connections. You will have to
>   open these ports in your firewall. If you have a NAT router, you need
>   to forward these ports to the local machine FileZilla Server is
>   installed on. Depending on your router model, you can either forward a
>   range of ports or you need to forward all ports individually.
>
> It is best to choose ports >= 50000 for passive mode FTP. A range of
>   50 ports should be sufficient in most cases.

Also, FileZilla Server needs to be told the address it should listen to:

> If you have a NAT router, you need to tell FileZilla Server your
>   external IP address or passive mode connections will not work with
>   clients outside your local network:
>
> 1. If you have a fixed external IP address, you can enter it in the
>      configuration dialog of FileZilla Server.
> 2. If you have a dynamic IP address, you can let FileZilla Server
>      obtain your external IP address from a special website
>      automatically. If in doubt, use this option.

Comment: Thank You for your spending your valuable time to answer my question.

I've also asked the ISP to open up the ports 21 & 990 to see if the connection is being established. They've opened up and all I get is nothing.

Comment: I did not expect them to do it easily, and am still a bit skeptical. If I were you, I would make a quick test: ask them to forward port 80 to your router and then see if you can access the router connecting to http://45.115.x.xxx. This is of course assuming your router is administered via a web interface on port 80, otherwise change port e.g. 443 for https or 22 for ssh, or any port where you know for sure the router is listening.

Comment: If they did setup port forwarding from the external ip address to your router, you would then need to setup the next port forward from your router to your Windows pc. The chain is so: external ip port 21 -> router port 21 -> Windows port 21. To check you have configured it correctly, you could try to connect to the router's address: it should forward the connection to the Windows machine.

Comment: I had them on phone and forwarded the ports, but nothing worked. It might be because there are like half-a-dozen routers between my router and the ISP's. Practically it's impossible to forward ports in all of them. I guess the only possible way is by means of an designated static public IP address.

Comment: Your provider should offer you a way of exposing at least one port. It may come at a cost in case of a dedicated ip address, but they should provide you with a solution lest you become interested in other ISPs.

Comment: Yeah, I've been vexed up for trying to setup this server, wasting 2 full days. Finally I had to drop the thought and so I've transferred the server to my friend's ISP. It has not been tested yet, but I shall let you know once done.

Comment: I've asked the ISP about the designated IP address, and it sounds way more costly. So I had to drop the thought of hosting on my network. Anyway, I got it to work on my friends static IP and it works perfect. Thank You for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up! Sometimes "home" ISPs have such an infrastructure that cannot support a server-like environment. My ISP's network is similar to yours, but I was lucky: they gave me a free public IP on request.

Comment: If my answer was useful to you, please consider accepting/upvoting it. Otherwise, you might want to post your own answer and accept it instead.

Comment: What you've requested has been done.